# How can I get all columns for a specific row from the database to another layout?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, listview

I'm working on an android project, where I want to get all the columns for a row (specific condition) and split them into TextViews.

I have a ListView with items:

[StartPage Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K1gm.png)

When I click on one of the items from the listview it will navigate to another layout and pass the listview item as string:

```
public void Select()
{
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewMovie);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            final String details = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MovieDetailsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("key", details);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
```

This is the other layout that it navigates to:
[MovieDetails Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPVjy.png)

Other than that I have a `MovieRepository`:

```
public class MoviesRepository
{
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private MyDBHelper myDBHelper;
    Movie movie;

    private String [] MovieAllColumns ={Movie.COlUMN_ID,
            Movie.COlUMN_NAME};

    private String [] MovieColumns ={Movie.COlUMN_ID,
            Movie.COlUMN_NAME,
            Movie.COlUMN_GENRE,
            Movie.COlUMN_YEAR};

    public MoviesRepository(Context context)
    {
        myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(context);
    }


    public void open() throws SQLException
    {
        //Open connection to write data
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public void close()
    {
        //Close connection to database
        db.close();
    }

    private Movie cursorToMovie (Cursor cursor)
    {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        movie.setName(cursor.getString(1));

        return movie;
    }

    public List<Movie> getAllMovies()
    {
        open();

        List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(Movie.TABLE_NAME, MovieAllColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Movie movie = cursorToMovie(cursor);
            movieList.add(movie);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        close();
        return movieList;

    }



    public void Create(Movie movie)
    {
        open();

        //helps you insert values to the table
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        //Put method - first column; what column do you want to be storing this ind. Second; what is the value you want to put ind
        values.put(Movie.COlUMN_NAME, movie.getName());
        values.put(Movie.COlUMN_GENRE, movie.getGenre());
        values.put(Movie.COlUMN_YEAR, movie.getYear());

        db.insert(Movie.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        close();
    }


    public void Delete(Movie movie)
    {
        open();
        //Deletes Movie by id
        db.delete(Movie.TABLE_NAME, Movie.COlUMN_ID + " = " + movie.getId(), null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

A DBHelper

And a Movie Model:

```
    public class Movie
{
    // property to help us handle the data
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String genre;
    private int year;


    //Getters and Setters of the properties
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getGenre()
    {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre)
    {
        this.genre = genre;
    }


    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }



//----------Start--------- Here we have defined the table contents (basically a blueprint of the table Movie) -------------------------------------

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "movie";
    public static final String COlUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COlUMN_NAME = "make";
    public static final String COlUMN_GENRE = "model";
    public static final String COlUMN_YEAR = "year";

//----------------------END----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

}
```

Hope you guys can help me figure it out

Comment: Do you mean Activity instead of Layout? Also post code for MovieDetailsActivity class; that is more useful.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's activity I mean

Comment: MovieDetailsActivity is pretty empty right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass entire object to an `Activity` and retrieve it there.

Calling Activity:

```
final Movie details = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MovieDetailsActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key", details);
```

Called Activity (here it is `MovieDetailsActivity`):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Movie details = (Movie)(intent.getExtras().getSerializable("key"));
```

Note that you'll have to make your class `Movie` Serializable.

```
public class Movie implements Serializable
```

Comment: With the name of the class that you use in your Adapter. I see you have Movie class as well. Do you use that in your Adapter? If yes, then you can keep it as Movie.

Comment: With my model class.name? 
It says cannot resolve method(String, Model.Movie)

Comment: Paste the exact error message here. Change your class declaration from `public class Movie` to `public class Movie implements Serializable`. See update.

Comment: How can I test/see if the movie item is passed?

Comment: In `MovieDetailsActivity`, do a Log or Toast using object `details`.
e.g. `Toast.makeText(this, (String)details.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` or `Log.d("MovieDetailsActivity", details.getName());`

Comment: When I do a toast, it returns like an empty bubble.. can't see it

Comment: Perhaps the value of name in details is empty. Post it as a new question. It's easier to handle that way.

Comment: One last thing I can can now get the Name and Genre, but not the year..
It says resource not found exception even though it's there.
Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to set the value of year to a place where it expects a ResourceId. Try doing only get. Post new question with relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep list of data(Movies in your case) in your adapter. And then pass not title, but id of object to another activity to be able to query this object from database by id.